# My yum is broken

Tags: python, centos

My error here,

```
    /usr/bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: 
libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

before this error,
I upgraded python 2.6 to 2.7 and libpython2.6 to 2.7 also.

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff919ff000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f9126b57000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f912693a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9126735000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f9126532000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f91262ae000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9125f19000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9127174000)
```

then I removed libpython2.6.
How do i fix it? ;(

Comment: python2.6 was the system python?

Comment: Try following the instructions at the bottom of this page:  https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18488